# Getting multiple simultaneous audio outputs from a computer

Tags: audio, sound-card, speakers

Brief:

My laptop has a 3.5mm audio output jack and I've attached 2 [usb sound cards](http://www.everbatim.net/store/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/n/andrea_usb_sa_custom_2_1.png) to it. This would avail 3 playback devices on the computer.

Is there a way (with any OS - windows/ubuntu/mac) that when I play a video, I could get its audio in all 3 outputs simultaneously and most importantly, I could set different equalizer levels for each one of them?

Thanks

Comment: you have 6 speakers, 3 pairs, with different EQ requirements? Are you trying to run them all at once? In the same room? Are they all self-amped? [I still don't think you're in for much joy, but just to get my idea of your configuration straight]

Comment: yup; 3 pairs to be played at once. And you are right, they all have their own amplifiers within them. Just need to trick the aux supply for them.

Comment: Not going to be easy in Windows. It's really something that it's not good at.

Comment: I use ubuntu too; just in case a solution is possible with it. We can remove the win-7 constraint.

Comment: Only Mac can do that kind of routing really - & tbh a) I'm struggling to think how to do it reliably even on there & b) I'm really not convinced it's going to sound any good even if you manage it. [I'm a sound engineer by trade]

Comment: As a first try, I'm taking it for experimental purpose a bit; so I won't be spending big money doing it when I'm not sure it's gonna sound good (like you do). Though any success would definitely lead to a permanent setup. Concerning Mac, I've only used it with virtualbox. I'm trying to find some electronic sound filters as a backup plan :) however being able to do it all or max by s/w is preferable.

Comment: What is the source of the signals for the USB sound cards?  Do you have separate control software for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can highly recommend Voicemeeter Banana. It's a great piece of software for Windows audio solutions. It is free/donation ware and it is quite powerful in managing audio on Windows. Right now I am looking for a Linux alternative, but I've had no luck at all.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>